# Getting average in the where clause using alias subqueries in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, query, aggregate

Hello I'm new at SQL and I've been asked to get the rent duration where rent duration is more than the average rent duration, but I can't seem to do it correctly. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code that I tried but is showing error:

[image: This is the code that i tired but is showing error]

Comment: Try to add an 'AND' between `DATEPART(..)=1 AND (SELECT ...`

Comment: It's a good practice to paste the code instead of a picture of it. Also, check the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and if you can provide those missing informations, it increases the chances of getting better help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the overall average rent using a window function, for example:

```
SELECT RentDuration,
       LEFT(StaffName, CHARINDEX(' ', StaffName)-1) AS StaffName,
       GroupName,
       LineRented,
       -- calculate overall average duration:
       AVG(RentDuration) OVER () AS AverageRentDuration
FROM RentTransaction AS RT
INNER JOIN Staff AS S ON RT.StaffID=S.StaffID
INNER JOIN CustomerGroup AS CG ON RT.GroupID=CG.GroupID
WHERE DATEPART(month, RentDate)%2=1  -- only Jan, Mar, May, Jul, etc.
```

However, you can't place a window function in a `WHERE` clause, so I would place the above query in a subquery or a CTE. I personally prefer the CTE, because it's easier to read:

```
WITH rents AS (
    SELECT RentDuration,
           LEFT(StaffName, CHARINDEX(' ', StaffName)-1) AS StaffName,
           GroupName,
           LineRented,
           -- calculate overall average duration:
           AVG(RentDuration) OVER () AS AverageRentDuration
    FROM RentTransaction AS RT
    INNER JOIN Staff AS S ON RT.StaffID=S.StaffID
    INNER JOIN CustomerGroup AS CG ON RT.GroupID=CG.GroupID
    WHERE DATEPART(month, RentDate)%2=1  -- only Jan, Mar, May, Jul, etc.
)

SELECT *
FROM rents
WHERE AverageRentDuration>RentDuration;  -- only rows with above-average duration.
```

The window function approach also allows you to define your window; for instance, you may want to compare to the average rent for this month, in which case, you would use something like

```
AVG(RentDuration) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(month, RentDate)) AS AverageRentDuration
```